# AngularJS, Laravel REST API

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, session, laravel

Im playing with Angular and laravel, so I have this RBAC Package of my own, and Im trying to make it work in a Rest way... I'm barely learning this... so my question is...

My package depends on php sessions, where an array with user roles and permissions is stored, so each time I run my filter to determine if the use should perform an action over a resource of the application or not it reads the session instead of querying the DB every time.

So... I have my routes functioning and all, but is there a way to access the user session through curl? ... better question is there a way to keep the user logged in so that way laravel knows where the session is store at?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want, but, PHP stores your session id as a cookie. And, `curl` can [load cookies from a file](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html). So, if you store your session id in a cookie file, and tell `curl` to load the cookies from that file, your problem is solved.

I hope this gives you a hint.

EDIT:
Laravel stores it's session coookie as `laravel_session`.